# insertar una imagen en los views de yii con el main.css

Tags: yii2

Quiero insertar una imagen usando el `main.css` de `yii` pero al usar este código:

```
.configuracion {
    background-image: url(configuration_13194.png) no-repeat;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Y luego usarlo en

```
echo "<div class='configuracion'> a </div>";
```

Simplemente no se ve pero si sale la linea de color roja del fondo.
Tampoco se donde debo colocar la imagen para que el `main.css` reconozca la dirección.

Answer (score 0):

Con lo siguiente puedes insertar una imagen de fondo en el div con class configuracion.

Esta imagen está ubicada en la carpeta imagenes dentro de la carpeta web. Básicamente lo que hace el código de la url es regresar un directorio atrás de donde se encuentra el main.css (sería la carpeta web) entra en la carpeta imagenes y selecciona la imagen deseada...

```
.configuracion {
    background: url(../imagenes/configuration_13194.png.JPG) no-repeat center center; 
}
```

Lo anterior debe funcionarte. También puedes probar otras opciones:

```
.configuracion {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../imagenes/configuration_13194.png.JPG) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```